# Scaling of Nodejs Socket.io Redis architecture

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, scalability

I know there are many q&a and resources on scaling Nodejs Socket.io, and I have read up quite alot. I am thinking of a simple deployment architecture on the cloud such as AWS that I will like to validate with the experts out here.

[image: http://oi48.tinypic.com/5mgx7b.jpg]

Is my diagram correct? Is this the way to scale? If so, how can I prevent Redis instance from becoming the single point of failure?

Answer (score 0):

Redis can be scaled too: http://redis.io/topics/replication

Comment: I read the link you provided but abit confused. There is replication (master/slave) and readonly slave. I thought in the master/slave, the slaves are also readonly? Is it possible to have a multi write masters for Redis?

Comment: I don't think that it is possible. This is a master slave setup used of HA rather then horizontal scaling.

Comment: In that case, is it possible to replace Redis with MySQL, Couchbase or others? Btw besides Redis scaling, is my concept of scaling Nodejs Socket.io with load balancer correct?

Comment: I've been told that you need a LOT of traffic to reach Redis's limits. Redis is extremely fast. And you can always run it a on bigger server with more cores and ram.

Comment: And you can always do sharding.

Answer (score 0):

Redis will probably [soon have a HA mode](http://redis.io/topics/sentinel) but in the mean time you could try another "store" for example the [MongoStore](https://github.com/kof/socket.io-mongo)